# Chapter Style- Report Class

Tags: memoir, chapters, report

[image]

I am looking for different types of chapter style formats for report class document. i like memoir class Veelo chapter style. how to do exactly the same format for report class document class

```
\documentclass{memoir} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\stockaiv 
\settrimmedsize{242mm}{165mm}{} 
\settrims{20mm}{20mm} 
\settypeblocksize{}{33pc}{1.618} 
\setlrmargins{}{}{1.5} 
\setulmarginsandblock{3pc}{3pc}{*} 
\setcolsepandrule{1pc}{0pt} 
\chapterstyle{veelo} 
\checkandfixthelayout 
\trimFrame 
\begin{document} 
\chapter{My first chapter} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where did you get the image from? Can't you get the source code? What does a document in veelo class look like and what exactly do you want to change by hand? Please show us some code to play around with!

Comment: \documentclass{memoir}

  \usepackage{graphicx}

  \stockaiv

  \settrimmedsize{242mm}{165mm}{*}
  \settrims{20mm}{20mm}
  \settypeblocksize{*}{33pc}{1.618}
  \setlrmargins{*}{*}{1.5}
  \setulmarginsandblock{3pc}{3pc}{*}
  \setcolsepandrule{1pc}{0pt}

  \chapterstyle{veelo}
  \checkandfixthelayout

  \trimFrame

  \begin{document}
    \chapter{My first chapter}
    
\end{document}

Comment: Why don't you just use `memoir`, use the `openany` class option and it does the same as the `report` class plus more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one possibility using the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package and the settings used by `memoir` for the style:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage{lipsum} %just to generate text for the example

\newcommand*\HUGE{\Huge}
\newcommand*\chapnamefont{\normalfont\LARGE\MakeUppercase}
\newcommand*\chapnumfont{\normalfont\HUGE}
\newcommand*\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\HUGE\bfseries}

\newlength\beforechapskip
\newlength\midchapskip
\setlength\midchapskip{\paperwidth}
\addtolength\midchapskip{-\textwidth}
\addtolength\midchapskip{-\oddsidemargin}
\addtolength\midchapskip{-1in}
\setlength\beforechapskip{18mm}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\filleft}
  {{\chapnamefont\chaptertitlename}%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{.8em}%
      \resizebox{!}{\beforechapskip}{\chapnumfont\thechapter}%
      \hspace{.8em}%
      \rule{\midchapskip}{\beforechapskip}%
    }%
  }%
  {25pt}
  {\chaptitlefont}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{40pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Demonstration of the veelo chapter style}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much it is working. how to increase the font size of the Chapter, and the width of the black bar. In my document after compilation it looks very small.

Comment: @user50229 Change `\LARGE` in `\chapnamefont` to the desired font switch; for example: `\newcommand*\chapnamefont{\normalfont\Huge\MakeUppercase}`.

Comment: @user50229 For the width of the bar, change the value for `\midchapskip`. If needed, consider open a follow-up question.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. I got it. How to get color to the chapter and the chapter number?

Comment: @user50229 Load `xcolor` in the preamble and use `\newcommand*\chapnamefont{\normalfont\color{red}\LARGE\MakeUppercase}
\newcommand*\chapnumfont{\normalfont\color{red}\HUGE}` changing `red` to the desired color.