# Setting Chapter style with bar

Tags: memoir, chapters, titlesec

I am using the setting from this post

[Chapter Style- Report Class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177144/chapter-style-report-class)

With the solution developed by [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage{lipsum} %just to generate text for the example

\newcommand*\HUGE{\Huge}
\newcommand*\chapnamefont{\normalfont\LARGE\MakeUppercase}
\newcommand*\chapnumfont{\normalfont\HUGE}
\newcommand*\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\HUGE\bfseries}

\newlength\beforechapskip
\newlength\midchapskip
\setlength\midchapskip{\paperwidth}
\addtolength\midchapskip{-\textwidth}
\addtolength\midchapskip{-\oddsidemargin}
\addtolength\midchapskip{-1in}
\setlength\beforechapskip{18mm}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\filleft}
  {{\chapnamefont\chaptertitlename}%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{.8em}%
      \resizebox{!}{\beforechapskip}{\chapnumfont\thechapter}%
      \hspace{.8em}%
      \rule{\midchapskip}{\beforechapskip}%
    }%
  }%
  {25pt}
  {\chaptitlefont}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{40pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Demonstration of the veelo chapter style}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

I found this problem. For example, the code works fine from Chapter 1 to 9, but after I have this problem, the Black bar disappear.

[image]

I tried to work to setting the line

```
\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{.8em}%
```

changing for example, from .8em to -1.8em but from 1 to 9 the black bar is longer than chapter >= 10

[image]

[image]

The solution given by @Bernard (see below) do not work if you set

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
```

For example I had the same problem

[image]

[image]

Improviing the code with the help of @Bernard (see below) I wrote the following code in order to have only numbers and not the write Chapter.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum} %just to generate text for the example
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{right=120pt}


\newcommand*\HUGE{\Huge}
\newcommand*\chapnamefont{\normalfont\LARGE\MakeUppercase}
\newcommand*\chapnumfont{\normalfont\HUGE}
\newcommand*\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\HUGE\bfseries}

\newlength\beforechapskip
\newlength\midchapskip
\setlength\midchapskip{\paperwidth}
\addtolength\midchapskip{-\textwidth}
\addtolength\midchapskip{-\oddsidemargin}
\addtolength\midchapskip{-1in}
\setlength\beforechapskip{18mm}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\filleft}
{{\chapnamefont\chaptertitlename}%
\rlap{\hspace{.8em}%
\makebox[\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+\hoffset+1in+30pt][s]{{\resizebox{!}{\beforechapskip}{\chapnumfont\thechapter}}\hfill%
\rule{46pt}{\beforechapskip}}%
}%
}%
  {25pt}
  {\chaptitlefont}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{40pt}{40pt}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Demonstration of the veelo chapter style}
\lipsum[1]

\setcounter{chapter}{22}
\chapter{Demonstration of the veelo chapter style}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Using this approach I got the following results

[image]
[image]

This is the most `unaesthetic` solution, but it's work.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum} %just to generate text for the example

\newcommand*\HUGE{\Huge}
\newcommand*\chapnamefont{\normalfont\LARGE\MakeUppercase}
\newcommand*\chapnumfont{\normalfont\HUGE}
\newcommand*\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\HUGE\bfseries}

\newlength\beforechapskip
\newlength\midchapskip
\setlength\midchapskip{\paperwidth}
\addtolength\midchapskip{-\textwidth}
\addtolength\midchapskip{-\oddsidemargin}
\addtolength\midchapskip{-1in}
\setlength\beforechapskip{18mm}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\filleft}
{{\chapnamefont\chaptertitlename}%
\rlap{\hspace{+34.8em}%
\makebox[\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+\hoffset+0in][s]{{\resizebox{!}{\beforechapskip}{\chapnumfont\thechapter}}\hfill%
\rule{46pt}{\beforechapskip}}%
}%
}%
  {25pt}
  {\chaptitlefont}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{40pt}{40pt}
\chapter{Demonstration of the veelo chapter style}
\lipsum[1]

\setcounter{chapter}{22}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\filleft}
{{\chapnamefont\chaptertitlename}%
\rlap{\hspace{+31.8em}%
\makebox[\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+\hoffset+0in][s]{{\resizebox{!}{\beforechapskip}{\chapnumfont\thechapter}}\hfill%
\rule{46pt}{\beforechapskip}}%
}%
}%
  {25pt}
  {\chaptitlefont}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{40pt}{40pt}


\chapter{Demonstration of the veelo chapter style}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a small modification of the code which does what you want, if I've well understood:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum} %just to generate text for the example

\newcommand*\HUGE{\Huge}
\newcommand*\chapnamefont{\normalfont\LARGE\MakeUppercase}
\newcommand*\chapnumfont{\normalfont\HUGE}
\newcommand*\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\HUGE\bfseries}

\newlength\beforechapskip
\newlength\midchapskip
\setlength\midchapskip{\paperwidth}
\addtolength\midchapskip{-\textwidth}
\addtolength\midchapskip{-\oddsidemargin}
\addtolength\midchapskip{-1in}
\setlength\beforechapskip{18mm}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\filleft}
{{\chapnamefont\chaptertitlename}%
\rlap{\hspace{.8em}%
\makebox[\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+\hoffset+1in][s]{{\resizebox{!}{\beforechapskip}{\chapnumfont\thechapter}}\hfill%
\rule{46pt}{\beforechapskip}}%
}%
}%
  {25pt}
  {\chaptitlefont}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{40pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Demonstration of the veelo chapter style}
\lipsum[1]

\setcounter{chapter}{22}
\chapter{Demonstration of the veelo chapter style}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

To format according to the latest wishes of the O.P. (only the chapter number and a black box above the title), here is a simple code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum} %just to generate text for the example

\newcommand*\HUGE{\Huge}
\newcommand*\chapnamefont{\normalfont\LARGE\MakeUppercase}
\newcommand*\chapnumfont{\normalfont\HUGE}
\newcommand*\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\HUGE\bfseries}

\newlength\beforechapskip
\newlength\midchapskip
\setlength\midchapskip{\paperwidth}
\addtolength\midchapskip{-\textwidth}
\addtolength\midchapskip{-\oddsidemargin}
\addtolength\midchapskip{-1in}
\setlength\beforechapskip{18mm}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\filleft}
{\rlap{%
\makebox[\dimexpr\paperwidth-\evensidemargin-\hoffset-1in][r]{{\resizebox{!}{\beforechapskip}{\chapnumfont\thechapter}}\quad%
\rule{46pt}{\beforechapskip}}%
}}%
  {25pt}
  {\chaptitlefont}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{40pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Demonstration of the veelo chapter style}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Demonstration of the veelo chapter style}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your Help. I am sorry but doesn't works. I still have the same problem. I use 
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\begin{document}
\input{Exercise1.tex}
\setcounter{chapter}{22}
\input{Exercise11.tex}
\end{document}

Comment: see the example above. I updated my post

Comment: @GianniSpear: This is a problem with the right margin, which is too short. If you load `geometry with option `verbose, you'll see in the .log file the right margin is nearly 90pt. You can choose `\geometry{right=120pt}` in the preamble, and add 30pt to the `makebox` command in `\titleformat`, like this: `\makebox[\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+\hoffset+1in+30pt]`.

Comment: yes I understand. Figth with Latex geometry it's not easy. For example see the new updatade in my post please

Comment: probably the best option is setting chapter by chapeter the black bar size

Comment: In your last code, did you suppress the word ‘Chapter’ purposely?

Comment: yes I am looking a style without chapeter word. See the new update. I find a "sort" of solution (not elegant)

Comment: Do you want the chapter number ending at the right margin  or inside the right margin (more or less like a marginal note)?

Comment: I can't figure out the " inside the right margin " solution. I am trying (with not success) to have the a number attached to the black-box (as the last output I posted). The code solution is far to be elegant!

Comment: @GianniSpear: I've updated  my answer with a simple solution to what you want.